# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error on multiple occasion in a wordpress theme I have been using recently but which hasn't been maintained unfortunately by its creator

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/multivendor/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php
> on line 1467

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/multivendor/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php
> on line 1469

This is what's on the line that gives the error:

```
public function end_controls_section() {
    $stack_name = $this->get_name();

    // Save the current section for the action.
    $current_section = $this->current_section;
    $section_id = $current_section['section'];
    $args = [
        'tab' => $current_section['tab'],
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `$this->current_section` return array which has 'section' and 'tab' element. Also for best practice, always check whether the array element is null or not.